# Multiple consumers in same consumer group. How does client.id get assigned to each consumer?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to understand the concept of having multiple consumers in the same consumer group to consume from the same topic.

Selecting RangeAssignor as partition.assignment.strategy.
If I have multiple instances deployed, then each instance/consumer should have it's own clientId.

What I don't understand is that all those instances should be exactly the same. But how and when does these client.id get assigned to each instance/consumer?

Comment: You can insert a UUID into the client id string, or use other runtime environment variables that are unique/computed per deployment, such as a hostname/ip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka Consumer Application should be configured with a mandatory config called `group.id`. This config is responsible for grouping the consumers (running across multiple instances). Kafka will group all the consumers based on this config and assign each consumer to a topic partition based on the selected strategy. At most one consumer gets assigned to a given partition to guarantee the ordering, though a consumer can read from multiple partitions.

`client.id` config is optional and if set it will allow you to easily correlate requests on the Kafka broker with the client instance which made it.
This will help for better monitoring and debugging purposes.